# How to create a non-unique index in sqlite?

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, indexing

How to create a non-unique index in sqlite?

I'm using vb.net to create the tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a non-unique index you would use the CREATE INDEX statement without the UNIQUE keyword. See the documentation for more information.

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html

**UPDATE:** If you are using the [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) provider, it has design time support in Visual Studio, so you can use it to create your indexes via Visual Studio.